# Error:Object [object Object] has no method 'msdropdown'

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery if somebody could tell me what i should do to get rid of this error?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: rootUrl + 'SchedulingProfile/GetVisitTypes',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var markup = '';
            for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value='" + data[x].Id + "' title='../images/trans.png'  label='background-color:#" + data[x].VisitTypeColor + "'>" + data[x].VisitTypeName + "</option>";
            }
            $('#ddlAnnualVisitType').html(markup).show();
            try {
                oHandler = $(".mydds").msDropDown().data("dd");
                //oHandler.visible(true);
                $("#ver").html($.msDropDown.version);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Error: " + e.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Error:Object [object Object] has no method `'msdropdown'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though from your question I am not very sure what is the issue but to use make sure below are true and you have added or implemented

1. you have to add the below js and css for using msdropdown

   jquery-1.3.2.min.js, jquery.dd.min.js , dd.css
2. `$(".mydds") is refering to a select`
   example `<select class="mydds">`